# SimpleModal jquery plugin issue on iOS5

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ios5, simplemodal

I have a problem with the SimpleModal jQuery plugin in iOS 5.0 and on. The thing is, I have a contact form and all is working great, but when I focus on a textbox in the contact form, it moves to the right and to the bottom of the screen. I'm using version 1.4.1 of the plugin, but I've also tested on the unreleased 1.4.2 version.